# What are the different types of 1:M work order objects?

Tags: maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1, there appear to be several different kinds of 1:M work order objects.

- These objects can be used to manage WOs that pertain to multiple assets or WOs that pertain to multiple tasks.

---

What would be an exhaustive list of all the different 1:M object types that are related to WOs?

Here's what I've come up with so far:

1. Parent WO `-->` Child WOs
2. WO `-->` Multi assets, locations, CIs
3. WO `-->` Meter readings (that generate WOs)
4. WO `-->` Tasks
5. WO `-->` Activities
6. WO `-->` Inspections

Other (technically not related to WOs):

1. Collections**
2. Saved queries** (assets & locations)
3. Routes (generates child WOs, multi-assets/locations/CIs, or routes)

<sup>** *Can be used to generate 1:M records via an automation script.*</sup>

---

Are there any others that are missing from that list?

Comment: I ask because I'm trying to figure out what option will work best for GIS asset inspection programs. I think the first step is to know what the OOB 1:M options are.

Answer (score 1):

Look under Database Configuration > Object WORKORDER > Relationships tab

If you look at the Relationship name, you will see the where clause Maximo will use to join the two objects together. That will give you some insight into which relationships you may be able to leverage.

Remember to look at the indexes and form your query to utilize indexes so your joins execute quickly. Any database client with an EXPLAIN PLAN feature should tell you if your query is executing quickly and if not, what is causing the delay (to an extent).